# IMS Service has stopped - Galaxy s8

Tags: android, galaxy, ims

Having updated my Samsung Galaxy S8 (SM - G950FD) to the latest Security Patch Level (1 November 2018), the IMS Service keeps crashing every 10 seconds with a popup "IMS Service has stopped." rendering the device extremely sluggish. I have wiped the data clean, cleared the messaging cache and even booted the device in Safe Mode - Yet the problem still persists. How do I get rid of this issue? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz9Ik.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

goto recovery mode on pressing home button + volume down button + power button. perform clear cache and data. The device should work fine.(All datas will be lost, perform backup before working on it)